# Problem with mapping entities to connection in eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have MySQL database with some tables there, and in my Workbench everything is fine, but when I make connection in eclipse, with that database, and open inspector in eclipse, to see tables, there is a problem that in table 'uloga' there are some columns that shouldn't be there. That is of course a problem, when I try to generate models using Hibernate I have in class Uloga fields that shouldn't be there, because Hibernate generates model classes from connection. This is model of my database: [image: This is model of my database]

This is how does it look in my workbench:
[image: This is how does it look in my workbench]

And this is how does it look in eclipse, when I make connection to db:
[image: And this is how does it look in eclipse, when I make connection to db]

Is there any solution for this issue ?

Comment: Do you have additional fields in your `Uloga` class in code, that are not present in the database?

Answer (score 1):

All of fields you don't want to be mapped to your database need to be annotated with `@Transient`. This annotation will 'tell' hibernate to ignore fields annotated with it.

This annotation is in `javax.persistence` package.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html

@Edit: 
You really don't need to define tables in your database while working with hibernate. It will define them automatically. I would try to drop table `uloga`, or at least redefine it, and then run the program.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have. [This is how does my class Uloga looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGKTU.png) There are four fields, that they are not in database. Fields like idGlumac, idPredstava and etc shouldn't be in this class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i know that, but there is another problem. I make classes from database, and when I make connection it makes me table Uloga with more columns then I have it in database. After that everything is a problem, making classes makes me errors and etc. Did I explain problem very well ?

Answer (score 0):

I found what problem was. I had in my database one more database, that have table with same name, and in mapping in eclipse when I make connection, connection had joining these two tables in one. Very stupid issue that I spent my last day on it. If you don't know how to spent your time in stupid way, please call me.